# Reverse binary reading

Tags: binary, bit, twos-complement, uint32

I have a [document](https://docs.mydolphin.org/Protocol.html#_2-data) that shows a data in HEX, and split it into multi part (head, TransactionID, MessageType and ...)
There is a problem in this document, and it is for example for TID they write something like this:

```
TID: 0xe0380000 = 14560
```

As i know converting `0xe0380000` to decimal will be `3761766400`, not `14560`.
I figured out that the way they read data is something like this:

For a given number such as `0xe0380000` they rotate the number and it will be `0x0000038e0` now the `0x0000038e0` in decimal is `14560`.
What is the reason for such a method to convert? Is it any thing to do with `Uint32` part in the documentation table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation table from the link that you've provided, the type for `TID` is `Uint32-LittleEndian` and the size is `4 bytes`. [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) indicates the order of bytes:

- **Little Endian (LE)**: - `14560 (10)` - > `e0 38 00 00`
- **Big Endian (BE)**: `14560 (10)` -> `00 00 38 e0`

Comment: Yes, but i forgot to answer my own question, thanks :)